# Where is the bug causing a heap-buffer-overflow?

Tags: c, malloc, address-sanitizer

I'm a rookie with C, but I am trying to solve a problem from LeetCode to get some more experience with hashtables. Running on my own Linux machine (of course without activating the address sanitizer flag, my program seems to run correctly, but solving the function in LeetCode always gives me an error for heap-buffer-overflow. I don't know how to interpret this and don't know what is causing the overflow, I can't find any place in my code where I'm stepping over any boundary.

This is the problem from LeetCode:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

This is my solution (I am using LeetCode's template for the "twoSum" function. I don't find a use for "returnSize" but I just left it there):

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */

struct hashTable
{
    int key;
    int value;    
};

int hash_number(int key, int size)
{
   return key%size; 
}

int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){

    int i;
    int hashNumber;
    int *returnArray;
    int complement;

    returnArray=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    returnArray[0]=-1;
    returnArray[1]=-1;

    struct hashTable *inputNumbers;
    inputNumbers=(struct hashTable*)malloc(numsSize*sizeof(struct hashTable));
    for(i=0; i<numsSize; i++)//filling up hash table
    {
        hashNumber=hash_number(nums[i], numsSize);
        inputNumbers[hashNumber].key=i;
        inputNumbers[hashNumber].value=nums[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<numsSize; i++)
    {
        complement=target-nums[i];
        hashNumber=hash_number(complement, numsSize);
        if((inputNumbers[hashNumber].key!=i) && (inputNumbers[hashNumber].value==hashNumber))
        {
            returnArray[0]=i;
            returnArray[1]=inputNumbers[hashNumber].key;
        }
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

When I do a test run on my own Linux machine, it works fine. But in Leetcode I get an error that looks something like this (I didn't copy the whole thing):

```
=======================================================================
30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x606000000070 at pc
READ of size 4 at 0x60000000080 thread T0 #2 0x7....... in __lib_Start_main....
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: Try some negative inputs.

Comment: what are the input parameters?

Comment: Since you're on Linux, enable address sanitizer, and use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you help yourself.  Valgrind, in particular, will probably diagnose the problem exceedingly accurately.  Remember to compile and link your object code with the `-g` option.

Comment: I think you'll find that if you set `*returnSize = 2;` in the `twoSum` function to indicate that you're returning two values in the array you've allocated, there's a chance that LeetCode will be happier with you.  Your calling code in your test harness should be using `for (int i = 0; i < returnSize; i++)` in the printing loop (after you pass `&returnSize` to the function), but I expect you are using `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`, so you don't run into that problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this "works fine" on your Linux machine. 7, 11, and 15 are all equal to 3 mod 4 -- where 4 is your value numSize. Furthermore, you don't initialize all your hashtable entries. On input [2, 7, 11, 15] with modulus 4, the only entries you initialize are 2 and 3. You leave 0 and 1 uninitialized. If target were say 10, when you evaluated if 10-2 = 8 were present in your table you'd access inputNumbers[0] which is uninitialized.

Comment: You can post a buildable code or use the online segfault diagnosis tool to diagnose it yourself.   https://segfault.stensal.com